# How to drag event when mouse over in fullcallendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I want to drag event when mouse over and I tried just call trigger mousedown and mousemove but it method not worked:

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
timeZone: 'UTC',
headerToolbar: {
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
},
editable: true,
dayMaxEvents: true, // when too many events in a day, show the popover
events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json?overload-day',
eventMouseEnter: function(info ){ // when mouse over
    console.log('eventMouseEnter')
    $(info.el).trigger('mousedown').trigger('mousemove') // it not worked
}
```

});

Any help pleas, tell me how can I drag event when mouse over in FulCallendar?

https://jsfiddle.net/bemulima/2ma7dL9f/5/

Comment: Why do you want to have these two events triggered on mouse enter ? Whats is the requirement or functionally that you want here ?

Comment: @Inder, just I have a popover block and this block shoved when event on mouse over (see screen [link](https://yadi.sk/i/Ilr5de70zINM1w) ). And in popover block has button for move event. I would like when client clicked to button "move event" call trigger for drag event

Comment: Support for dragging is built in - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-dragging-resizing . You don't need to write your own code for it.

Comment: @ADyson,  fullcalendar not support drag when mouse enter, only when mouse down.

Comment: Ok. Personally I would find it extremely irritating if an event started moving just because I happened to move my mouse across it. Maybe your users would like it, but to me that's not a desirable feature. IMO the user should actively choose to start the dragging, by clicking the button.

Comment: @ADyson sure, if it works right away - it extremely irritating. But for me it wil work throught by popover where showed some buttons for action ([see popover](https://yadi.sk/i/Ilr5de70zINM1w)). When client clicked button for move event only then will work drag by coursor.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks makes a lot more sense. Glad you found a solution (below), it's got my upvote :-)

Answer (score 1):

I found solution. Maybe this not better solution but it worked with natural simulate mousedown.

```
eventMouseEnter: function(info ){
    console.log('eventMouseEnter')
    var evt = new MouseEvent("mousedown", {
                            view: window,
                            bubbles: true,
                            cancelable: true,
                            clientX: info.jsEvent.pageX,
                            clientY: info.jsEvent.pageY,
                            /* whatever properties you want to give it */
                        });
                        info.el.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bemulima/2ma7dL9f/7/